# Cannot fetch students from db and display it in the angular front end no error is visible

Tags: angular

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <td>Name</td>
              <td>Profile</td>
              <td>Cgpa Criteria</td>
              <td width="275" align="center">Action</td>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
             <tr  *ngFor="let company of companies">
                <td>{{company.name}}</td>
                <td>{{company.profile}}</td>
                <td>{{company.cgpaCriteria}}</td>
                <td width="275"> 
                    <a class="btn btn-info" routerLink="/showCompany/{{company._id}}">Detail</a> 
                    <a class="btn btn-success"  routerLink="/editCompany/{{company._id}}">Edit</a>
                    <a class="btn btn-info"  routerLink="/matchCriteria/{{company.cgpaCriteria}}/{{company.profile}}">Find Students</a>
                    <a class="btn btn-danger" (click)="deleteCompany(company._id)">Delete</a>
                </td>
             </tr>`enter code here`
          </tbody>
        </table>
```

This is company.html file which displays the list of all companies . This portion is working 
when we click on find students button , the students who match the company criteria must be displayed . 
There is no error but the students are not being displayed.

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import {CompService} from '../../comp.service'
import {Company} from '../../company'


@Component({
  selector: 'app-companies',
  templateUrl: './companies.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./companies.component.css']
})
export class CompaniesComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
  public compService:CompService 
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
   this.getCompanies(); 
  }

  model = new Company();
  companies:Company;

  getCompanies()
  {
    this.compService.getCompanies().subscribe(companies=>{this.companies = companies; 
  }) 
 }

 deleteCompany(id){
 this.compService.deleteCompany(id)
 .subscribe(()=>{
 this.getCompanies()
 })

 }

}
```

This is the companies.component.ts file which contains function

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <td>Name</td>
              <td>Department</td>
              <td>Cgpa </td>
              <td width="275" align="center">Action</td>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
             <tr  *ngFor="let student of students">
                <td>{{student.name}}</td>
                <td>{{student.department}}</td>
                <td>{{student.cgpa}}</td>
                <td width="275"> 
                    <a class="btn btn-info" routerLink="/showCompany/{{student._id}}">Register Student</a> 
                    <a class="btn btn-success"  routerLink="/editCompany/{{student._id}}">UnRegister Student</a>
                    <a class="btn btn-info"  routerLink="/matchCriteria/{{company._cgpaCriteria}}/{{company.profile}}">Register Students</a>
                    <a class="btn btn-danger" (click)="deleteCompany(company._id)">Delete</a>
                </td>
             </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
```

this is the register.component.html file

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

    import {FormBuilder, FormGroup , Validators} from '@angular/forms';
    import { ActivatedRoute, Params, Router } from '@angular/router';



    import {StudService} from '../../stud.service'
    import {Student} from '../../student'

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-register-student',
      templateUrl: './register-student.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./register-student.component.css']
    })
    export class RegisterStudentComponent implements OnInit {

      constructor(

      public studService:StudService,
        public route:ActivatedRoute,
         public router:Router
      ) { }


      model = new Student();
      students:Student;

      cgpa = this.route.snapshot.params['cgpa'];
      department = this.route.snapshot.params['department'];


      registerStudents()
      {
      this.studService.getStudentBasis(this.cgpa,this.department)
      .subscribe(student=>{
      this.model = student;
      })

      }
       ngOnInit() {
      this.registerStudents()
      }

    }

this is the registercomponent.ts file which is used when we click on find students

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


@Injectable()
export class StudService {


  constructor(private http:Http) { }

    getStudents()
    {
    return this.http.get("http://localhost:3000/api/students").map(res =>res.json());
    }

    getStudent(id)
    {
    return this.http.get("http://localhost:3000/api/show/"+id).map(res =>res.json());
    }

    addStudent(info)
    {
    return this.http.post("http://localhost:3000/api/registerstudent",info).map(res =>res.json());
    }

    deleteStudent(id)
    {
    return this.http.delete("http://localhost:3000/api/removestudent/"+id).map(res =>res.json());
    }

    updateStudent(id , info)
    {
    return this.http.put("http://localhost:3000/api/updatestudent/"+id,info).map(res =>res.json());
    }

    getStudentBasis(cgpa,department)
    {

    return this.http.get("http://localhost:3000/api/findStudent/"+cgpa+"/"+department).map(res=>res.json());
     }

}
```

this is the studService.ts file which contains all the functions 
[This is the page which displays the list of companies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDGBB.png)

[This is the page which opens when we click on find students as you can see no students are visible but when I run it on localhost:3000 the function written in backend works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAa57.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The "tags" attached to your question are meant to categorize "what your question is actually about", and NOT "every single component in your application stack". This question shows code for the Angular front end only, therefore the **only** appropriate tag is "angular". Also note that is a different thing to "angularjs" which you also tagged the question with. Keep tags relevant and accurate to what you are actually asking about.